# Вложенность объектов. Занимают-ли вложенные объекты излишнюю память в сравнении с обычными объектами и стоит-ли использовать вложенность в целом?

Tags: javascript, c#, объекты, память

Приветствую всех читателей.
В процессе реализации достаточно затратного по памяти проекта столкнулся с такой ситуацией, что из-за огромного количества свойств, хранящихся в каждом отдельном объекте, стало трудно анализировать отдельные его свойства. Причиной заполнения объекта единым перечнем свойств без дополнительной вложенности стало воспоминание, моя собственная выдумка или, возможно, просто дурной сон, в котором я, вроде бы, слышал, что вложенность может занимать избыточную память.

Я решил окончательно разобраться в данном вопросе и хотел бы узнать мнение более опытных программистов по этому поводу. Буду благодарен вам за ваши ответы и надеюсь, что вы поможете мне разобраться.

Comment: Какой язык-то? В языках вроде C/C++/Rust вложенность не стоит ничего

Comment: @andreymal, а как же размер указателя на "вложенный" объект?:)

Comment: @andreymal, прошу прощения, мне следовало уточнить это в вопросе. Языки, такие как: С#, JS

Comment: В C# вложенные типы как правило не используются, так как вложенные типы усложняют архитектуру приложения, и являются дополнительным источником ошибок. И нет, это никак не влияет на расход ресурсов.

Comment: @Grundy так не надо хранить указатель, надо хранить непосредственно сам объект (: Вот например 26 структур, вложенных друг в друга, занимают всего 1 байт (а если убрать value:u8, то будет вообще 0 байт) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6c6f4dc5aa3da6599da298142ed9bfc

Comment: @aepot, благодарю вас и всех написавших комментаторов. Считаю ваш комментарий ответом на вопрос и благодарю вас за этот ответ!

Comment: @aepot а как насчёт накладных расходов на обработку указателей/ссылок?

Comment: @andeymal вы типы с экземплярами точно не путаете?

Comment: @aepot ну текст вопроса вроде подразумевает именно экземпляры (особенно в случае JS), или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @andreymal ну тогда это зависит от задачи. Здесь уже ООП решает задачу - инкапсуляция. Выше я писал именно про типы. Что касается расходов, они зачастую окупаются, например, попробуйте определить, что лучше, вложенный массив `[][]` или двухмерный массив `[,]`. С точки зрения памяти - второй лучше, но как только вы столкнулись с задачей перестановки строк или добычи данных из строки, становится очевидно, что не все так очевидно. Плюс нюансы с двумя баунд-чеками при обращении к ячейке данных.